# Select qry to using 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below query:

```
SELECT 
     --a.DateEntered,
     --a.InventoryId,
     a.SKU, a.QtyOnHand,
     b.Dateentered AS VDateEntered,
     b.GoLive, b.DateOnSite, b.CostPrice,
     --a.CurrentPrice,
     m.name AS Status,
     hrf.category, hrf.department, hrf.BrandedOB, hrf.Division,
     hrf.Fascia,
     (a.QtyOnHand * b.CostPrice) AS Cost_Value,
     NULL AS Item_Quantity, NULL AS Item,
     NULL AS Season, hrf.Company,
     (a.QtyOnHand * b.CurrentPrice) AS Sellilng_Value,
     b.merchandisingseason, b.CostPrice AS Costprice_RP,
     b.CurrentPrice, b.InventoryID,
     -- a.AverageUnitCost,
     -- a.AverageUnitCost AS RP_Stk_AverageUnitCost,
     -- a.CurrentPrice AS RP_Stk_Current_Price,
     -- a.Statusid,
     -- a.Quantity_Sign,
     (a.QtyOnHand * b.CostPrice) AS Cost_Value_RP,
     (a.QtyOnHand * b.AverageUnitCost) AS AWC_Value     
     -- a.StockReconciliationId,
     -- a.AverageUnitCost,
FROM
    [dbo].[FC03QTY] a
JOIN 
    dbo.inventory b ON a.SKU = b.SKU
LEFT JOIN
    (------Hierarchy-------
     SELECT 
         ih.InventoryId, hry.category, hry.department,
         hry.BrandedOB, hry.Division, hry.Fascia, hry.Company
     FROM
         (SELECT
              ihn.HierarchyNodeId, ihn.InventoryId
          FROM bm.InventoryHierarchyNode IHN
          GROUP BY ihn.HierarchyNodeId, ihn.InventoryId) IH
     JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              g.categoryid, g.category, h.department, i.BrandedOB,
              j.Division, K.Fascia, L.company
          FROM 
              Category g (NOLOCK)
          JOIN
              Department H ON g.departmentid = h.departmentID
          JOIN
              BrandedOB I (NOLOCK) ON h.BrandedOBID = i.BrandedOBID
          JOIN
              Division j (NOLOCK) ON i.divisionid = j.divisionid
          JOIN
              Fascia k (NOLOCK) ON j.fasciaid = k.fasciaID
          JOIN
              company l (NOLOCK) ON k.companyid = l.companyid
          GROUP BY
              g.categoryid, g.category, h.department,
              i.BrandedOB, j.Division, K.Fascia, L.company) HRY ON ih.HierarchyNodeId = hry.CategoryId
     GROUP BY
         ih.InventoryId, hry.category, hry.department,
         hry.BrandedOB, hry.Division, hry.Fascia, hry.Company) HRF ON b.inventoryid = hrf.inventoryid
JOIN
    inventorystatus m (NOLOCK) ON b.statusid = m.statusid
```

It is using 2 tables -

- [dbo].[FC03QTY] a

and

- dbo.inventory b

that are joined at the SKU level.

`[dbo].[FC03QTY]` is on the scratch database and `dbo.inventory` is on the reports database.

How can I get my query to use these tables if they are on 2 different db?

Any advice greatly received.

Comment: databasename.dbo.tablename if on the same server.  If on different servers you need to use linked servers.

Comment: Just an un-related comment, why not do SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY without using aggregate functions? Saves typing, and easier to add/remove columns.

Comment: Also somewhat unrelated, it is considered good practice to refer to database objects by a schema name and the object name.  You should do that for `inventorystatus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql server the syntaxis for tables is `[database name].[schema name].[table name]`

So you need something like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM 
     Database1.dbo.Table1 as  A, 
     Database2.dbo.Table2 as  B
```

Comment: @PipRon7 Since it worked for you remember that you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.